# Right Margin for Tablet

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, margin

I've been asked to help with a website that has been coded by another company. The site is responsive, when using the 320px - 1024px stylesheet a right margin of about 20px appears.

I've been through the stylesheet 4 times and can't for the life of me figure out what is causing this. I'm now completely stuck as to where this might be occurring.

I'd be very grateful if someone could give me a pointer.

[Link to offending website](http://dtapartnership.icreondemoserver.com/?page_id=176)

Here is a screenshot of the margin:- [Screenshot](http://dtapartnership.icreondemoserver.com/margin-issue.gif)

Many thanks in anticipation.

Phill

Comment: Where is that margin? The only margin I see is the (probably desired) margin in the header

Comment: `'Debug my website'` is probably offtopic for SO. But regardless, a screenshot of the offending margin would be useful to those that don't mind helping.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will include a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this element:

```
<div class="left-inner-section tp_top">...
```

It's width is set to 100%...

```
.left-inner-section {
  width: 100%;
  // ...
}
```

... and it starts 35 pixels from the left:

```
.left-section,
.left-inner-section {
  left: 35px;
}
```

Setting the left value to 0 seems to remove the margin. However, be careful about other side effects.

Comment: Thank you very Sebastian, that's done the trick. Much appreciated :-)